# how to get the middle curve(a series of middle points) from a series of triangle?

Tags: python, math

Assume that I have a series of triangles like:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

how can I get the middle curve like:

[image: image3]
[image: image4]

And as I know, a series of triangle also can be regarded as a series of points, and then the question become how can I get the middle curve from a series of point?

The series of triangles is stored in wavefront obj file which looks like

```
v 8.384618 0.736892 -0.618098
v -6.179957 -1.130277 0.008627
v -0.000020 5.198666 3.527076
...
f 1 2 3
f 2 3 4
f 4 5 6
```

Here a [sample input](https://gofile.io/d/8jenKd)

Comment: I think we need to know more, for example, what does the data for the "series of triangles" look like? The illustrations look as if it might just be a sequence of segments connecting the midpoints of common sides. Or it might be connecting a sequence of centroids, which would be easier if you get the triangles in order.

Comment: @TimErickson just a obj file

Comment: the triangulation significantly simplifies this... are the "curves" always just a lsingle layer of triangles or there are more layers in parallel (2 or more triangles per width) . If just one then you just make a list of shared triangle edges and compute the center point of each edge ... if more layers you make a list of unshared edges (outlines) and  then find points on oposite sides of 2 outlines that are connected by  inner edges. if found the closest ones then just compute mid point between them and that is it ...

Comment: however I see you have only `v` entries in the file you posted ... do you have original one with the triangulation (with also `f` entries) ? If not you would need to do convex hull to obtain outlines ... or use DIP thinning algorithms instead

Comment: @Spektre Yes I have this [file](https://srv-file20.gofile.io/download/EWT43A/235_1.OBJ).Can you show me the process by code or fake code?

Comment: @Spektre I am not sure what you mean about "if more layers you make a list of unshared edges (outlines) and then find points on oposite sides of 2 outlines that are connected by inner edges. if found the closest ones then just compute mid point between them and that is it".（I have more than one layer）

Comment: @Spektre Especially how to find two points on opposite sides of 2 outlines that used for computing the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not code in python (and usually I am reluctant to answer rookie python questions due bad experience with rookie python "coders" they usually just blindly copy paste code and do not grasp what has been done and than just endlessly ask questions about the same things that where already explained. So I will not provide any code more like hints and algorithm how to do this instead).

Well the last [input wavefront file](https://gofile.io/d/EWT43A) you shared looks correct (has both points and triangulation). Now there are 2 possible configurations:

**Single layer of triangles per line:**

[image: single layer]

**Multiple layers of triangles per line** (two "parallel" triangle strip layers in image):

[image: multi layer]

In both the the black lines are outlines and gray are inner lines. First we need do detect which line is outer and which is inner. That is easy when triangulation is present.

1. **load your wavefront into memory**

   create 2 arrays one holding your points `(v)`, and one holding your triangular faces (f). Lets call the points `pnt` and faces `fac`. Beware wavefront address points from `1` instead of `0` so if your code access arrays from `0` either insert empty point or decrement or faces indexes. In C++ it would look like this:

   ```
   float pnt[points][3];
   int  fac[triangles][3];
   ```

   Also beware some wavefronts mix primitives. Not using just triangles but convex polygons in some entries. For those triangulate (simple for loop creating triangle fan).
2. **list of lines**

   we need a list of all lines used. So create a list that has 2 point indexes per line:

   ```
   int  lin[triangles][2];
   ```

   and feed it from the `fac`. Each triangle has 3 lines. So per each triangle add 3 its lines into `lin` but store them ordered (for example lower index will be first), Here your example:

   ```
   f 1 2 3
   f 2 3 4
   f 4 5 6
   ```

   so (after decrementation of indexes):

   ```
   int fac[][3]=
       {
       { 0,1,2 },
       { 1,2,3 },
       { 3,4,5 },
       };

   int lin[][2]=
       {           
       { 0,1 },{ 1,2 },{ 0,2 }, // { 0,1,2 },
       { 1,2 },{ 2,3 },{ 1,3 }, // { 1,2,3 },
       { 3,4 },{ 4,5 },{ 3,5 }, // { 3,4,5 },
       };
   ```

   Now just sort the lines ascending

   ```
   int lin[][2]=
       {
       { 0,1 },
       { 0,2 },
       { 1,2 },  //this line is here twice
       { 1,2 },  //this line is here twice
       { 1,3 },
       { 2,3 },
       { 3,4 },
       { 3,5 },
       { 4,5 },
       };
   ```

   The inner lines are shared between neighboring triangles so it should be in the `lin` array twice. After such sorting they are consequent so just scann the `lin` and separate duplicate and distinct lines into 2 list `in[][2]` and `out[][2]`.

   ```
   int in[][2]=
       {
       { 1,2 },
       };

   int out[][2]=
       {
       { 0,1 },
       { 0,2 },
       { 1,3 },
       { 2,3 },
       { 3,4 },
       { 3,5 },
       { 4,5 },
       };
   ```

   In full data there will be more or less the same number of inner and outer lines for single layer of triangles and multiple times more inner lines than outer for multi layers of triangles... Your cutted example has just single shared edge (because you copied just few of the `f` lines...).

**Single layer of triangles per line:**

This one is easy. Just take your `in[][2]` and compute the midpoint:

```
p = 0.5 * ( pnt[in[i][0]] + pnt[in[i][1]] )
```

so create a list of all mid points like this and that is your output. If you Also need the polyline info then just connect mid points of edges that share the same vertex

[image: mid line]

**Multi layer of triangles per line:**

it is easier to cast perpendicular planes from outlines testing plane/line intersection and then just use the mid point ignoring inner lines completely:

[image: mid points]

for example:

1. **for each `out` line**
2. **find its center point (red)**
3. **cast perpendicular plane from it (aqua)**

   the plane lies at the center of line and its normal is the line direction. In 2D it would be just (half)axis or line but in 3D you need plane.
4. **take closest hit (green)**

   simply check all `out` lines for the [plane/line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection) and remember closest hit.

   To make it more robust you can use half plane checking just the inward side (using `in` lines connected to the lines vertexes as inward direction ignoring hits on the opposite side)
5. **compute center between the lines (magenta)**

   this is your mid point. Again if you want polyline then join midpoints of lines that share the same vertex, and do not use lines that has been already hit.